# Cannot connect web application to a SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, web

I am building a web application so I want to connect the web application on local machine to a company SQL Server. When copying the connection string from the same web application sitting on the server to my local web config I get the following error

> "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)".

Your help will be appreciated....

Comment: post your connection string

Comment: Here is the connection string : <add key="connection_string" value="Data Source=SERVER036\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=IAPBWebsiteTest;User ID=username; password=password;" />

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: Either your connection string is just wrong (wrong server and/or instance name, wrong credentials), or then your SQL Server **Express** you're trying to connect to isn't configured for **remote connections** (those are **OFF** by default)